# Optimize for happiness and equality

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, np-complete

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem:

There are $N$ students who can choose to enroll into $C$ courses, each of them has a set of 3 preferences $P = \{c_1, c_2, c_3\}$ about the courses they would like to enroll into (in order of preference). Each student must enroll in two courses. However, each course $c_i$ has a fixed capacity $k_i$.

Since I suppose it's a NP problem, I would like to solve it using Local Search, but I don't know how to optimize for happiness and equality (minimize variance) between students at the same time. Thanks

Comment: I think you need to say more about your "happiness" and "equality" functions. Is h(#1,#2)-h(#1,#3) = h(#1,#3) - h(#2,#3)?   Is equality satisfied by randomization or are you trying to minimize the variance of happiness?

Comment: For equality minimize variance as you said. For happiness maximize sum of individual happiness: if student i is enrolled in a course which doesn't belong to his/her preferences then its value is 0, otherwise the value depends on the order of the course in the preference (say 3 for 1st preference, 2 for 2nd and 1 for 3rd). So individual happiness is sum of first choice plus sum of second choice.

Comment: And is happiness linear?  Also, how do we compare your two test functions?  It is likely, for instance, that low variance will imply lower mean happiness.  How do we weigh that trade off?  That is, how much group happiness will I give up in order to achieve equality?

Comment: So happiness is linear, yes?  h(#1,#2) = 3+2 = 5, h(#1, #3) = 4 and h(#2,#3)=3 (and 5-4 does equal 4-3).

Comment: @lulu yes, it's linear

Comment: General point:  the "trade off" question is usually where these things get hard to model, there being no natural way to compare variance to happiness.  In practice, people generally start with an arbitrary trade off scheme and look at the results.  If the results are too extreme, one way or another, the weighting factors are rebalanced until the results feel reasonably satisfying.  Hard to be scientific about that.

Comment: Ok, I thought of using a weighted sum of the two, but maybe there is a more elegant way to do it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26257/discussion-between-lulu-and-federico-capello).

Comment: Comment #1: I don't think this problem is NP-complete.

Comment: Comment #2: You can compute optimal happiness by looking at things from the Course perspective.  The largest capacity course has the largest potential for total happiness.  The second-largest capacity course has the second largest potential.  And so forth.  Now, these large-capacity courses may not be preferred by any students, but you can compute the largest total possible happiness for the number of students possible, and you can optimize as to how close you get to *that* number within your actual preferences.

Comment: @FedericoCapello You need a functional relation between the utility on one hand and the ordered preferences and the variance one the other hand. . In this case the utility for one person and one preference combination would be $U_p(c_1,c_2,c_3)-U_v(Var(c_1,c_2,c_3))$

Comment: Any given student can have one of three feasible assignments: {c1,c2}, {c1,c3}, or {c2,c3}.  If we look at the happiest possible student ({c1,c2}) vs. the least possibly happy ({c2,c3}), we see an excess variance of 2 compared with assignments of {c1,c3} for both students, with no change in total overall happiness.  If we look at a slightly less happy case ({c1,c3} and {c2,c3}) and swap that to {c2,c3} for both students, we see a unit decrease in happiness (bad) and variance (good) yielding no change to the objective function.  Maximize H, then swap to optimal V.

Comment: It can be the case that, for capacity constraints, student is assigned to a course he/she doesn't like

Comment: In order to optimize for equality I can maximize the least happy student and for general happiness I use the average happiness and adjust the values with weights. At least the values will be in the same scale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose a fitness function `f` such that `f(students) = average(happiness(students)) + minimum(happiness(students))`